# Ruby Hash of Hash, Adding new items

Tags: ruby, hash

I am storing a Hash of a Hash.

```
filelists { filename => [another hash] }
anotherhash {id => method}
```

where filename is the filename, id is the server id and method is the type of lock, read or write.

```
def addfile(client, input)
  #byebug
  serverid = input.split(' ')[2].strip
  filename = input.split(' ')[1].strip
  puts "RECEIVED FILE NOTIFICATION: " + serverid + " FILENAME: " + filename
  if @filelists.include?(filename)
    @filelists[filename] = {serverid.to_i => 'r'}
  else
    @filelists[filename] = Hash.new
    @filelists[filename] = {serverid.to_i => 'w'}
    puts "New Hash Created for: " + filename
  end
  client.puts "File Accepted: " + filename
  puts "File Accepted: " + filename + "\n\n"
  printfiles(filename)
end
```

What happens is when adding another element to the hash, it just deletes the previous element.

After the first server uploading the files the has is:

```
 {"ds.txt"=>{1=>"w"}, "fileserver.rb"=>{1=>"w"}}
```

Then when the second server starts uploading the files, it just rewrites over the previous hash.

Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `@filelists[filename] = Hash.new` has no effect, as the empty hash is overwritten in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Was using the wrong format. Needed to change to

```
@filelists[filename][serverid.to_i] = 'r'
```

Final code

```
def addfile(client, input)
#byebug
serverid = input.split(' ')[2].strip
filename = input.split(' ')[1].strip
puts "RECEIVED FILE NOTIFICATION: " + serverid + " FILENAME: " + filename
if @filelists.include?(filename)
  @filelists[filename] = {serverid.to_i => 'r'}
else
 **@filelists[filename][serverid.to_i] = 'r'**
  puts "New Hash Created for: " + filename
end
client.puts "File Accepted: " + filename
puts "File Accepted: " + filename + "\n\n"
printfiles(filename)
end
```